# Wordpress : Using Object Storage for Assets Files

Tags: wordpress, assets, cdn, digital-ocean, object-storage

I want to store my **wordpress theme asset files or wordpress asset files** into **DigitalOcean Object Storage**.

I have successfully implemented the system for wp-content/uploads files to store those library images into DigitalOcean Object Storage through a plugin.

**Now, I just want to transfer my other css, js, images files into Object Storage and load them from the Object Storage link?**

How Can I do that ?

As an example,

there are some files in **wp-includes > css, js, images**

**Where are these files are used and how the links of these files are working?**

Now How can I upload these files to my object storage and load from the object storage link? Is there any plugin out there? or Do I need to change anything manually ?

Comment: no people to help ?

Comment: Something like this: https://medium.com/@kee_ross/sync-your-wordpress-media-with-digitalocean-spaces-b730eb7e19fc

Comment: @gdfgdfg Yes, I have used this plugin for the images to store on DigitalOcean Object Storage, but I am talking about other static files such as js, css, sass, theme static files or wordpress static files. How will I make the workable link for those files when those are uploaded to the DigitalOcean.